# MVC 5 - Pass object to a shared view

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-views, onexception

I am developing a MVC 5 internet application and have a question in regards to passing an `object` to a shared `view`.

I have a `view` called `CustomError.cshtml` in the shared folder. This `view` has the following model type: `@model CanFindLocation.ViewModels.CustomErrorViewModel`

How can I pass an object of type `CanFindLocation.ViewModels.CustomErrorViewModel` to this `view` from the `protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)` function in a `controller`?

Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    Exception e = filterContext.Exception;

    if (e is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = false;
        customErrorViewModel = customErrorService.GetDefaultCustomError(customErrorType, "Test message.");
        RedirectToAction("CustomError", customErrorViewModel);
    }
}
```

Instead of the `view` being shown, the following function is called:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user373648: what Exception is thrown into Application_Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can return view as you want, so I usually put values into TempData and make a redirection to homepage or whatever landing page.

Homepage check is there is value into this Viewbag and show error if there is error.

Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected void SetError(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            TempData["UIError"] = string.Format(message, args);
        }
    }
```

In in my shared (master) layout view:

```
@if (TempData["UIError"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                @TempData["UIError"]
            </div>
        }
```